# Pass JavaScript Object Data into Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, modal-dialog

I've looped through each object and passed each object's data to it's own div along with a button, in each div, that opens a modal window when clicked and displays the data for only that particular object.

However, my problem is, when i test each button to see if it's data displays I would see that the last object's data is displayed for all of the objects modal window. any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>


<title>Help</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-    
2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
<script 


<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384- 
JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style>

.box{
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:grey;
}
.box2{
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:white;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box" class="box"></div>


<script>


var radio = [
    {
        name:"106 power",
        address:"1620 sw 11th st",
        phone:"305-892-9927"
    },
    {
        name:"99 jamz",
        address:"1900 sw 19th st",
        phone:"305-892-9900"
    }



]

for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
    var qb = radio[i].name;
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += "<div class='box2'>" + radio[i].name + "<br>" + radio[i].address + "<br> <button type='button' id='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>" + "Click me!" + "</button></div>";

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#main-content").html(qb);
});
});



};


</script>




<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;            
</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body " id="main-content">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close
</button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>







</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to
>   identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more
>   than one.

So you should change id with class

Here is your code :

```
<button type='button' id='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>" + "Click me!" + "</button>
```

Here is modified code:

```
<button type='button' class='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>" + "Click me!" + "</button>
```

Also you have loop where you are trying to attach event on **#button** click which attach several event on #button and when you click on button it fire many time so if you want to avoid this many time fire you should attach event outside from loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
    var qb = radio[i].name;
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += "<div class='box2'>" + radio[i].name + "<br>" + radio[i].address + "<br> <button type='button' id='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>" + "Click me!" + "</button></div>";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button").click(function(){
       $("#main-content").html(qb);
   });
});
```

Also if you want to show radio.name in content when click button you should use data- attribute it is my advice. change your code with this:

```
for (i = 0; i < radio.length; i++){
    var qb = radio[i].name;
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML += "<div class='box2'>" + radio[i].name + "<br>" + radio[i].address + "<br> <button type='button' class='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-radio-name='" + qb + "'>" + "Click me!" + "</button></div>";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
       $("#main-content").html($(this).data('radio-name'));
   });
});
```

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: try using event delegation and use `.on('click',function)` rather than `.click(function)`

Comment: if i wanted to pass html along with the object data, so to give the data some structure, how would one go about that?

Comment: You should put JSON.stringify(objectData) in data- attribute and if you want to get this object you should use JSON.parse($(this).data('something'))